# I installed and run gcc but dpkg says : package gcc is not installed, why?

Tags: software-installation, gcc, dpkg

I downloaded and installed `gcc-4.9` (using the basic `./configure` `make` `make install`). I can compile code and everything works fine. But `dpkg -s gcc` claims thats gcc is not installed. However, `dpkg -s gcc-4.9` returns a valid output.
I want to link package `gcc` to `gcc-4.9` so that `dpkg` claims the presence of package `gcc`.The reason for me to do this is because i need to manually install a `.deb` package (using dpkg) & it needs `gcc` package to be installed.

```
root@afr0ck:~/Desktop/Packages# gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

root@afr0ck:~/Desktop/Packages# dpkg -s gcc
dpkg-query: package 'gcc' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

root@afr0ck:~/Desktop/Packages# dpkg -s gcc-4.9
Package: gcc-4.9
Status: install ok installed
```

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` says the package is not installed and it is right since you didn't install it with the packaging tool as you should have.

When using a package manager (as `dpkg` or `apt-get`), you should avoid manual installation at all costs unless you wish to experience conflicts for the rest of your life.

You should now correct your mistake and install it properly with `apt-get install gcc` or with related tools `apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: Ok. But is there any way to add the `gcc-4.9` package as `gcc` in `dpkg` ?

Comment: The reason for me to this is because I'm doing some experimentations on an old kernel based distribution and I'm installing old software that is no more supported in official repos.

Comment: Why would you need an old gcc version to compile old code?

Comment: At the beginning i tried installing a newer version but i had troubles with it so i moved to this older version and it just worked fine so i didn't bother changing it. I assume there isn't any way to do what i wanted to do ?

Comment: Well if it works, it's ok.  But if you want to manually install the packages, why complain that the package manager doesn't know them?  You should already know that since you're voluntarily bypassing it.